# Запятые в сложноподчиненном предложении

Tags: школьное-задание, пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с домашним заданием. Благодарю заранее.

> Через сотни лет они догадались обкладывать костер валунами, чтобы раскаленные угли не раскатывались пылающего костра по пещере.

Для чего нужна запятая после слово валунами? Объясните.

> Он заметил, что огонь, пылавший внутри кольца, превращал глину в прочный материал".

А для чего нужны здесь все запятые? А теперь можете помочь в этом еще мне:

- непрерывно - почему не пишется слитно?
- раскатывались - слово без приставки
- пещера - а почему не пищера?
- валунами- а почему не волунами ?
- заделывать - почему с "ы" a не "о"?

Все точно напишите, пожалуйста. Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, здешние администраторы не очень одобряют в вопросах школьные задания, но, так как вы попросили объяснить, а не просто решить, я думаю, они сжалятся.    
Очевидно, уровень ваших знаний невысок, поэтому начнём с азов. В предложениях, в которых надо расставить запятые, надо сначала найти грамматическую основу, то есть подлежащее и сказуемое. *"Через сотни лет **они**(подлежащее) **догадались**(сказуемое) обкладывать костер валунами, чтобы раскаленные **угли**(подлежащее) **не раскатывались**(сказуемое) пылающего костра по пещере"*. В предложении две грамотические основы (надо убедиться, что они это не однородные члены), значит, их надо разделить знаком препинания. В нашем случае - запятой. Теперь вопрос: где ставить эту запятую? Находим средство связи (то, чем связываются эти две части). Средства связи - это либо союзы, либо союзные слова. Их список было бы хорошо хоть раз увидеть воочию ([ссылка на плохой сайт с нормальным ответом](http://otvet.mail.ru/answer/233344667/)). В таких простых случая, как ваш, запятая ставится перед союзом (забудем пока о союзных словах).

Во втором предложении первая запятая ставится по тому же принципу, что и в первом. Вторая и третья обособляют *(=выделяют запятыми)* определительный оборот (надо знать члены предложения), так как он распространен (в нем не одно слово, а несколько) и стоит после слова, которое он описывает. *"Огонь(какой?), пылавший внутри кольца, превращал..."*

Наречие "непрерывно" пишется слитно потому, что образовалось от прилагательного "непрерывный", а прилагательные пишутся с "не" слитно.   
"Раскатывались" - приставка "рас-", так как есть однокоренное слово "катать".   
"Пещера" - словарное слово. Его следует запомнить.   
"Валунами" потому, что есть слово "валун", а оно словарное.  
"Заделывать". Если в настоящем или будущем времени глагол оканчивается на -ываю (-иваю), то в неопределенной форме и прошедшем времени надо писать суффикс -ыва- (-ива-). Если в настоящем или будущем времени глагол оканчивается на -ую (-юю), то в неопределенной форме и прошедшем времени пишется суффикс -ова- (-ева-) ([скопипащено отсюда](http://www.yamal.org/ook/doc/ook-suff.htm)).

Как же тяжело в простых словах объяснять русский язык. Наверное, у меня преподавать плохо получается. Уважаемый спрашивающий, людям, которые сидят на этом форуме будет довольно тяжело ответить на ваши вопросы в доступном языке, так как основные термины и правила всё же стоит учить по учебнику русского языка, который у вас, скорее всего, есть. В нём всё должно быть расписано более понятным для вас языком. Если вам что-то не понятно, спросите у своего преподавателя, он должен объяснить.

Comment: Я не разобралась еще, какая наивысшая оценка за доступный и правильный ответ, поэтому моя оценка 5 - как в былые школьные годы.

Comment: @Соан, отличной оценкой также считается голосование "за"(палец вверх) ответ участника.

Comment: Когда ребята просят помощи в решении заданий, то мы всегда идем навстречу. Закрываем вопросы только тогда, когда задания выкладывают без пояснений и явно школьные упражнения.)))  
Администрация

Comment: Конечно, тут понятно, что школьное задание, но вопрошающий попросил объяснить, а не просто решить, поэтому я и пояснил, пытаясь меньше вдаваться в термины и тому подобную глубину русского языка.

Answer (score 1):

Хорошо, конечно, что есть желающие помочь, но всё-таки надо бы без ошибок: "две граМОтические основы" (грамматические), "определительный оборот" (наверное, причастный?); "прилагательные пишутся с "не" слитно", но не всегда, а только если нет отрицания, противопоставления и спец. слов;"пещера" - словарное слово, но оно имеет отношение к слову "печь", а это помогает запомнить написание.

Comment: Обособленное определение - это не обязательно причастие.  Про иные варианты с "не" я не стал говорить, так как уровень знаний вопрошающего недостаточно велик, я подстраивался. Почти все словарные слова можно объяснить этимологией, но я не стал вдаваться в такие дебри, поэтому объяснил всё словарностью. А последнее это опечатка.

Comment: Если задававшему вопрос объяснять нормативным рус. яз., вряд ли он поймет изложенное, потому что автор вопроса не знает школьной программы. Это не осуждение, это беда школьного образования - школы выпускают детей, которые не знают РОДНОГО языка, к сожалению.

Comment: Опечатки надо править. А на ошибки надо обращать внимание. Имхо.
Это говорит человек, который в силу разных причин лепит тех и других без меры. И прошу всех без стеснения мне на все это указывать в тех случаях, когда я сам не поправил за какое-то разумное время.

Другое дело, что, указав на опечатку, не стоит раздувать вокруг неё менторство не полстраницы. Тем более не стоит предлагать исправить правилоьный вариант на заведомо ошибочный.

Comment: @behemothus опечатки у вас встречаются довольно часто (даже здесь: "не полстраницы"). Раз просите, буду указывать.